# Get Parents of a Control in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, iextenderprovider

I have `Panel1` inside this `Panel2` and inside this `Panel3` ... So imagine like

```
Panel1->Panel2->Panel3->button1
```

So How can get a path string like

```
string path=\Panel1\Panel2\Panel3\button1
```

if I want to get all Parents of **button1**.
And Can I do that using with defining a class which implement IExtenderProvider, so is it possible to make it in design time.

Comment: `Control.Parent` could be what you want. Could you elaborate on the design-time concept - like how would setting the string differ from design-time compared to run-time?

Comment: @JeremyThompson ahh my bad... I mean I dont want to use tag property of Control to assign tag property control Path. I want to use Extender Class so In my program I want to get that property's value (path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extension method to get all of the parents' names as an `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetControlPath(this Control c)
    {
        yield return c.Name;

        if (c.Parent != null)
        {
            Control parent = c.Parent;

            while (parent != null)
            {
                yield return parent.Name;
                parent = parent.Parent;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a property of a UserControl that I added to the Project that will make use of it:

```
public partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ControlPath
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Join(@"\", this.GetControlPath().Reverse());
        }
    }
}
```

After building, drag the user control onto the Form from the toolbox. Be sure to nest it inside other controls pretty good. I nested 3 panels and put it in the innermost panel similar to your example. Here's what the properties look like at Design time:

[image: User Control Properties]

This should be applicable to any class you make that derives from `Control`. `IExtenderProvider` seems irrelevant here.